# jetty ShutdownThread memory leak with spring batch

Tags: jetty, spring-batch, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using spring batch to read a csv file and perform a feign call for every row of the file.

This is the core class for my Job:

```
package it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.config;

import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.core.config.JobCompletionNotificationListener;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.core.domain.job.NexiJobInterface;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.manager.*;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.manager.factory.BatchSetupFactory;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.manager.factory.Setup;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.model.DataInput;
import it.nexi.digitalreview.batch.model.DataOutput;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersValidator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class NexiJob implements NexiJobInterface {

    @Autowired
    private BatchSetupFactory<DataInput, DataOutput> batchSetupFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    public Job build(String templateId, ByteArrayResource inputResource, FileSystemResource failsResource) {

        Setup<DataInput, DataOutput> setup = batchSetupFactory.getSetup(templateId);

        if(setup == null) return null;

        AbstractNotificationProcessor<DataInput, DataOutput> abstractNotificationProcessor = setup.getAbstractNotificationProcessor();
        AbstractCsvNotificationMultiFormatWriter<DataOutput> abstractCsvNotificationMultiFormatWriter = setup.getAbstractCsvNotificationMultiFormatWriter();
        AbstractCsvNotificationReader<DataInput> abstractCsvNotificationReader = setup.getAbstractCsvNotificationReader();
        AbstractFileVerificationSkipper abstractFileVerificationSkipper = setup.getAbstractFileVerificationSkipper();
        AbstractCsvNotificationWriter<DataOutput> abstractCsvNotificationWriter = setup.getAbstractCsvNotificationWriter();
        JobCompletionNotificationListener jobCompletionNotificationListener = setup.getJobCompletionNotificationListener();


        abstractCsvNotificationReader.setResource(inputResource);
        abstractCsvNotificationWriter.setResource(failsResource);

        TaskletStep csvFileToNotificatorStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("csvFileToNotificatorStep")
                .<DataInput, DataOutput>chunk(10)
                .reader(abstractCsvNotificationReader)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(abstractFileVerificationSkipper)
                .processor(abstractNotificationProcessor)
                .writer(abstractCsvNotificationMultiFormatWriter)
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("csvFileToNotificatorJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobCompletionNotificationListener)
                .flow(csvFileToNotificatorStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRestartable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecution execution) {
        this.execute(execution);
    }

    @Override
    public JobParametersIncrementer getJobParametersIncrementer() {
        return this.getJobParametersIncrementer();
    }

    @Override
    public JobParametersValidator getJobParametersValidator() {
        return this.getJobParametersValidator();
    }

    public BatchSetupFactory<DataInput, DataOutput> getBatchSetupFactory() {
        return batchSetupFactory;
    }
}
```

What I'm noticing, is that at some time (after about 300 to 400k rows), the heap is no more freed from the gc. That's what I see about heap and cpu:

[image]

As you can see, the gc worked fine at a first time, just before 17:00, but then it started to degrade ending up filling the whole heap.

(there were 3 runs of the batch, this explain the heap profile between 17:30-18:00 and 19:15-20:00. In those sections the batch was idle, but still keeping objects in memory)

I performed an heap dump with the heap at maximum, and found out what's following:

[image: Java Static org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ShutdownThread._thread]

[image]

It looks like jetty is causing the memory leak. I searched the web and out this was a common problem that's been solved with newer versions of jetty. I tried to update but nothing changed.

That's the dependency tree:

```
 it.nexi.digitalreview.batch:send-notifications-from-csv:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
 |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.14:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.14:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
 |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
 +- it.icbpi.digitalreview.archcomps:nexi-core-pt:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- it.icbpi.digitalreview.archcomps:nexi-core-pt-om:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- it.icbpi.digitalreview.archcomps:nexi-core-abs-om:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.16:compile
 |  \- it.icbpi.digitalreview.archcomps:nexi-core-abs:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.19:compile
 |     |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.8:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
 |     |  |     \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
 |     |  |        \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
 |     |  |           \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
 |     |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.1.4:compile
 |     |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.1.4:compile
 |     |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  |     \- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.0:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
 |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
 |     |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.4:runtime
 |     |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |     |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 |     +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
 |     +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
 |     +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.6:compile
 |     |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
 |     +- com.netflix.feign:feign-core:jar:8.18.0:compile
 |     +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:jar:3.7.7:compile
 |     |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.7.7:compile
 |     +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:jar:3.7.7:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
 |     |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.10:compile
 |     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
 |     +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.6:compile
 |     |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |     +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
 |     |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
 |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
 |     +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.7.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:4.0.2:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.195:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.13.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.6:compile
 |     |  |  \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-serialization:jar:1.5.6:runtime
 |     |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.8.8:runtime
 |     |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.7:runtime
 |     |  \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.6:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.26-incubating:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     |  +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:2.1.1:compile
 |     |  \- org.webjars:d3js:jar:3.4.11:compile
 |     \- it.icbpi.digitalreview.archcomps:nexi-core-abs-jwt-validator:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |        \- it.nexi:plugin-api-gateway:jar:1.0.0-RELEASE:compile
 |           +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  \- com.netflix.zuul:zuul-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
 |           +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 |           +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |           |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.4.12:compile
 |           |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
 |           |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
 |           |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
 |           |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
 |           |  |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
 |           |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:runtime
 |           |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
 |           |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0:runtime
 |           |  |  \- com.netflix.governator:governator-api:jar:1.12.10:runtime
 |           |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.4.12:compile
 |           |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator:jar:1.12.10:runtime
 |           |  |  |  \- com.netflix.governator:governator-core:jar:1.12.10:runtime
 |           |  |  |     +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:4.0:runtime
 |           |  |  |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-grapher:jar:4.0:runtime
 |           |  |  |        \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:4.0:runtime
 |           |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
 |           |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
 |           |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
 |           |  \- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |           +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
 |           \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |              +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
 |              |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
 |              |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-codec:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |              |     |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:3.0.3:compile
 |              |     |     +- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
 |              |     |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
 |              |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |              |     \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
 |              \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-bus:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |                 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |                 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |                 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.14:compile
 |                 |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
 |                 |  +- org.springframework:spring-tuple:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
 |                 |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-tuple:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
 |                 \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
 |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:9.3.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.jvnet:animal-sniffer-annotation:jar:1.0:compile
 |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:9.3.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix:jar:9.3.1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.2.0:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
 |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
 |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
 |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
 |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
 |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |     \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.10.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |  \- com.netflix.servo:servo-internal:jar:0.10.1:runtime
 |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.1.1:runtime
 |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
 |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.1.10:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.4:compile
 |     |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:runtime
 |     +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
 |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.7:compile
 |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
 |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
 +- it.nexi.digitalreview.batch:core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.4.0:compile
 |  +- it.nexi.digitalreview.batch:rest-notificator:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  \- it.icbpi.digitalreview.common:notificator-domain:jar:8.0.15.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     \- it.icbpi.digitalreview.common:rest-firebase:jar:8.0.15.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.50:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
 |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.3:compile
 |  +- jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:jar:1.0:compile
 |     |  \- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
 |     +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.9:compile
 |     |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
 |     |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
 |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
 |     \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
 |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
 |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
 |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:compile
 +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
 \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
```

any clue on how to solve my problem?

------UPDATE------

I think the problem belongs to my ItemPrecessor. Here a snippet of wahat it does:

```
public class ICNotificationProcessor<I,O> extends AbstractNotificationProcessor<NotificationDataModel,NotificationDataModelWithState> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ICNotificationProcessor.class);

    private CustomNotificatorServiceClient customNotificatorServiceClient;

    private Tracer tracer;

    private String serviceId;

    public ICNotificationProcessor(CustomNotificatorServiceClient customNotificatorServiceClient, Tracer tracer, String serviceId){
        this.customNotificatorServiceClient = customNotificatorServiceClient;
        this.tracer = tracer;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationDataModelWithState process(final NotificationDataModel notificationDataModel) {

        Span span = tracer.createSpan(notificationDataModel.getIdAsString());
        long traceId = span.getTraceId();
        long spanId = span.getSpanId();

        MDC.put(NexiBaseServiceConst.Mdc.TRACE_ID, String.valueOf(traceId));
        MDC.put(NexiBaseServiceConst.Mdc.SPAN_ID, String.valueOf(spanId));

        //perform feign call with traceId and spanId in request

        tracer.close(span);

        return notificationDataModelWithState;
    }

}
```

Looks like that's not the correct way to handle spans.

Comment: Can you run a `mvn dependency:tree` and edit your question to add those details? (it's more useful then the copy/paste of the `<dependencies>` xml elements.)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thanks, you're right. done

Comment: `It looks like jetty is causing the memory leak. I searched the web and out this was a common problem that's been solved with newer versions of jetty`: Indeed, I see nothing related to Spring Batch from what you shared.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine not related to spring batch, but to jetty ShutdownThread. Anyway I updated my post, I think I found the problem, but can't figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The section from `dependency:tree` that I'll focus on ...

```
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.3:compile
 |  +- jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
 |  \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
```

This is a curious mix.

Jetty 9.4.x is Servlet 3.1, not Servlet 4.0 (unlike what spring-boot-starter-jetty has declared)

Jetty 9.4.x is also using ASM 7.0 (or better), not 5.1

Add this to your pom.xml to force all Jetty artifacts to upgrade properly to the version you specify.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-bom</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.29.v20200521</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add this entry, and then look at your `dependency:tree`
The Jetty (and asm) artifacts will be upgraded.
However, the servlet-api jar will not change (and I'm unsure if its necessary to change it)

Comment: Hello Joakim, I think I found the problem, I'm running a load test right now. In case it is solved I'll post the solution, otherwise I'll try yours

Comment: I edited my post, still not found the solution, but probably found the problem